# compound proposition logically equivalent

Tags: logic

I can not solve this question 
Find a compound proposition logically equivalent to $p \to q$ using only the logical operator $\downarrow$.

Comment: What's the truth table for $\downarrow$?

Comment: @GitGud - It is "NOR" : $p \downarrow q$ is *true* only when *both* $p$ and $q$ are *false*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh, I see, it's the negation of [Sheffer's stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke).

Comment: @GitGud No, it's not the negation of Sheffer's stroke.  It's the negation of disjunction.  It does have a relationship to the Sheffer stroke though.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Right, I was led to a mistake due the [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke#Truth_table)'s firstline in the link above is $0\, 0$ instead of $1\, 1$.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple; let start with :

> $\lnot p \equiv p \downarrow  p$.

Then :

> > $p \rightarrow q \equiv ((p \downarrow p) \downarrow q) \downarrow ((p \downarrow p) \downarrow q)$.

In order to check the definition, we have to use the truth-table for $\downarrow$ : it is *true* only when both $p$ and $q$ are false.

This fact justify the definition of $\lnot p$ as $p \downarrow p$.

For the *conditional*, we will work by steps:

> $((p \downarrow p) \downarrow q)$ is $\lnot p \downarrow q$ [see the definition of $\lnot$ above].

Thus, the complete formula is simply : $\lnot ( \lnot p \downarrow q)$.

Now we may check that the only case when it is false (i.e.$0$) is when $p=1$ and $q=0$.

*Note.* You can see this paper on [Adeqaute set of connectives](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~lila/logic/adequate.pdf) for a general overview of the topic.

Comment: Could you enhance this answer to show _how_ you found this?  (I have an idea, but I think the OP would want to know as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Given propositions $p$ and $q$, the propositon $p \downarrow q$ is given by the following truth table:

$$
\begin{align}
p \qquad &  q  & p \downarrow q \\
T \qquad & T  & F \\
T \qquad & F  & F \\
F \qquad & T  & F \\
F \qquad & F  & T 
\end{align} 
$$

Thus we have
$$
T \downarrow T \equiv F, \ \ \ T \downarrow F \equiv F, \ \ \ F \downarrow T \equiv F, \ \ \  F \downarrow F \equiv T. \tag{0} 
$$

In fact, we have the logical identity
$$
p \lor q \equiv \overline{p \downarrow q}. \tag{1} 
$$

We further note that
$$ p \downarrow p \equiv \overline{p}, \tag{2} $$
because when $p$ is True, we have $T \downarrow T$, which is False, and when $p$ is False, we have $F \downarrow F$, which is true.

And, we also note that
$$
\begin{align} 
p \lor q &\equiv \overline{\overline{p \lor q}} \\ &\equiv \overline{p \downarrow q} \qquad \mbox{[ using (1) above ]}\\
&\equiv \big( p \downarrow q \big) \downarrow \big( p \downarrow q \big).
\end{align}
$$
Thus we have the logical identity
$$
p \lor q \equiv \big( p \downarrow q \big) \downarrow \big( p \downarrow q \big). \tag{3} 
$$
Now we note that
$$
\begin{align}
p \rightarrow q &\equiv \overline{p} \lor q \qquad \mbox{[ using the conditional-disjunction equivalence ] } \\
&\equiv \left( \overline{p} \downarrow q \right) \downarrow \left( \overline{p} \downarrow q \right) \qquad \mbox{[ using (3) above with $\overline{p}$ in place of $p$ ]} \\
&\equiv \big( (p \downarrow p) \downarrow q \big) \downarrow \big( (p \downarrow p) \downarrow q \big) \qquad \mbox{[ using (2) above ]},
\end{align}
$$
as required.